# Android smart power management using sensor data

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm working on an Android application that needs to scan nearby Wi-Fi access points on a regular basis. Currently the scan takes place every 2-3 minutes, which requires registering a `BroadcastReceiver` to capture the scan results, calling `WifiManager`'s `startScan` method and processing the results (something that also requires network calls in my case). This loop consumes a lot of energy, and I want to improve my power consumption by implementing a smart power policy for the app.

Aside from scanning only on "busy hours" (for example, stopping the loop at night), I'm thinking about using the accelerometer through the `SensorManager` to detect whether the device is stationary (placed on a table) or in motion (in the user's pocket while walking, for example). Then, by determining if the device is moving, I can adjust the scan frequency (reduce when it is stationary, and increase when the device is in motion).

I have a few questions on the matter:

1) Will tracking accelerometer data on a regular basis be more power efficient than running the scan loop every 3-5 minutes? How much power will tracking the accelerometer really cost?

2) How can I determine if the device is stationary or in motion? I've seen many question online talking about detecting shakes and tilts, but there's not a lot of information about natural motion detection. Also, how frequently should I sample the sensor?

Comment: You could try getLastKnownLocation() { i think thats the method name off the top of my head } to query the GPS and see if the device is 'stationary' - though a difference stationary than what the Accelerometer would give you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `ActivityRecognitionApi` class included in the google play sevices which is optimized for such goals. This class gives a method : `requestActivityUpdates` which is optimized to return device state with minimum consumption of power.

> The activities are detected by periodically waking up the device and
>   reading short bursts of sensor data. It only makes use of low power
>   sensors in order to keep the power usage to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I second Fouwad Wahabi’s answer to your question.
I would recommend taking another approach to the track accelerometer and your user’s activities. I’d integrate a free SDK (available online) such as: 
1.  Tranql
2.  Neura
3.  Atooma
Some of these SDK’s send you the details of the user’s activities as soon as they occur and use less than 1% of your battery.